# how to show jdialog at start of application in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, dialog

i am building an application where I want to show dialog to ask user for username and password. its not showing at start of application . can you help in this regard

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: public season() {
       
    
        initComponents();
       setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
      
           dialog_login.setVisible(true);

Comment: Edit your question to add the code. We need to see ALL the relevant code, otherwise we can't understand what happens.